# Working nvidia drivers for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, kernel, graphics

I know compatibility issues with ubuntu and nvidia drivers aren't exactly new, but i usually always find people detailing combinations of kernels/driver version which work for them. I haven't been able to find something that works for my system, so here goes:

I have Ubuntu 20.04, using kernel 5.4.0-56-generic.

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and i believe it installed with nvidia-450 drivers, which caused the system to freeze regularly, after which i had to shutdown manually every time.

In an attempt to solve this, i performed a driver autoinstall `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and i got the nvidia-455 drivers with which my system doesn't event boot any graphic interface. I boot the computer and i just get black screen with access to terminals (tty1,tty3...), where i need to change back to noveau drivers. With noveau drivers everything works fine, but i would like to be able to install a driver option that is stable for my system.

So my final question is: Which is best? Should i change my kernel version? Should i install a specific nvidia driver version which is stable with ubuntu 20.04? If yes, which versions are known to work good?

Thank you all in advance
(sorry about inaccuracies, this is the first time i ask a question)

Adittional information on my graphics drivers:

```
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:149 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**EDIT: hi, so.  I've disabled secure boot and i still get the same issue. It was suggested that i may have nvidia drivers blacklisted somewhere. I can't seem to find how or where. If anyone has any ideas that would be cool. I'll keep searching and trying stuff i guess. And i've tried also the version nvidia-440 drivers with the same result :(**
thanks!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and all should work. It is no a matter of driver version.

Comment: hi! i just went and did this right away, disabled secure boot. Then did the ```sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall``` , and rebooted, and still i have the same issue. black screen and i can only access the tty terminals

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. Probably the `nvidia` module is blacklisted somewhere.

Comment: oh. ok. thanks. i guess i will search about blacklisted nvidia then. do you have any idea how i can change this? do i need to blacklist noveau? should i have a configuration file somewhere?

Comment: It can be somewhere in `/etc/modprobe.d`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the help Pilot6!
I tried different things to figure out what may be causing my computer to not load nvidia drivers at all.
I am posting it as an answer because it may be useful to someone else.

I found this thread: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-sceen-after-install-nvidia-390-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-nvidia-gt-630m/123354

In which someone seems to have a similar issue on 18.04 bionic beaver. Following instructions there I was able to solve my issue (at least it looks solved :) )
by performing the following steps:

1. delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf (i didn't have this file anyways....)
2. install the driver from repo `sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-driver-450`
3. make sure nvidia-prime is installed `sudo apt install nvidia-prime`
4. switch to nvidia `sudo prime-select nvidia`
5. remove stray blacklist files `sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`
6. update the initrd `sudo update-initramfs -u`
7. and finally `reboot`

So my system is now running on nvidia-450 drivers, i will update if there are any random freezes or apparent issues, but i didn't want to leave this post hanging without any closure...